# How to model an event-driven system for replays

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's say I have a system to which I can upload documents via an API. There are three services:

- the `UploadService` - responsible for providing a HTTP endpoint
- the `StorageService` - responsible for storing uploaded documents
- the `FileCabinet` - responsible for managing a file cabinet (e.g. categories, hierarchy, etc.)

I'm trying to learn more about event-driven architecture, and now I am trying to come up with one.

The `UploadService` can receive a command `UploadCommand` and emits a `DocumentUploaded` event once it created a
unique identifier for the uploaded document.

The `StorageService` listens for the `DocumentUploaded` event. Once it receives such an event, it creates a `StoreDocument`
command and handles it. The outcome is a `DocumentStoredEvent`.

The `FileCabinet` listens also for `DocumentUploaded`. Once it receives such an event, it updates its state to include
the uploaded document. The outcome is a `DocumentFiledEvent`.

What I don't get is, that when I would try to replay the events of the system, I would get duplicate events, since
the services themselves trigger events. Am I missing some concepts here?

Comment: The concept you’re missing is that event handlers should be idempotent.

Comment: So events should be idempotent and commands do not have this property?

Comment: Can you make an example for what you precisely mean by "getting duplicate events" and why that is an issue?